# Sum up multiple rows to just 1 row

Tags: typescript

I have this result from an api that returns x rows and i want to convert it to just 1 row.
It will add equipmentOrdered, quantity, and services. I am using typescript in angular. Any help would be appreciated thank you.

```
 {id: "1", equipmentOrdered: "Monitor", quantity: 2, services: "Maintenance", channelPo: "testest", customerPo:" abc"}
 {id: "1", equipmentOrdered: "Keyboard", quantity: 1, services: "Cleaning", channelPo: "testest",  customerPo:" abc"}
 {id: "1", equipmentOrdered: "Mouse", quantity: 2, services: "Software maintenance", channelPo: "testest", customerPo:" abc"}
 {id: "1", equipmentOrdered: "Video Card", quantity: 1, services: "Debug", channelPo: "testest",  customerPo:" abc"}
 {id: "2", equipmentOrdered: "Keyboard", quantity: 2, services: "Software maintenance", channelPo: "testest", customerPo:" abc"}
 {id: "2", equipmentOrdered: "Video Card", quantity: 1, services: "Debug", channelPo: "testest",  customerPo:" abc"}
```

Like this:

```
{id : "1", equipmentOrdered: "Monitor and 3 more", quantity: 6, services: "Maintenance and 3 more", channelPo: "testest",  customerPo:" abc"}
{id : "2", equipmentOrdered: "Keyboard and 2 more", quantity: 3, services: "Software maintenance and 1 more", channelPo: "testest",  customerPo:" abc"}
```

EDIT:

```
 getCustomPo(tenantId) {
      this._purchaseOrderService.getCustomPurchaseOrder(tenantId).subscribe({
        next: res => { this.customPo = res  },
        error: err => console.log(err)
      })
  }
```

Comment: Can you just use an Array.reduce()?
What have you tried? How is the data being supplied to the component/service. More details or a working example help us help you

Comment: @joshvito hi this is a the arrays are result of a query from an api. and i need to display it to a table as 1 row. sorry i am quite new to typescript and javascript.

Comment: can you share a snippet of code that is making and getting the data from the api?

Comment: @joshvito added the api call. is that what youre looking for?

Comment: yes, that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a BehaviorSubject to store the return data. And then use a `pipe()` operator to reduce the array into the object you want.

Something like this...

```
// interface to define the objects from the API call
export interface IMyPo {
  id: string,
  equipmentOrdered: string,
  quantity: number,
  services: string,
  channelPo: string,
  customerPo: string
}

// some.component.ts
customPo = new BehaviorSubject<IMyPo[]>(null); // set the default value
customPoAggregate: Observable<IMyPo>;

ngOnInit(){
  // set up another Observable to subsribe to
  this.customPoAggregate = this.customPo.pipe(
    filter(d => !!d) //only process non-nulls
    map(cpos => copos.reduce((aggregate, item, index, set) => {
      return {
        id: item.id,
        equipmentOrdered: aggregate.equipmentOrdered + ', ' + item.equipmentOrdered,
        quantity: 0 + aggregate.quantity + item.quantity,
        services: aggregate.services + ', ' + item.services,
        channelPo: item.channelPo,
        customerPo: item.customerPo,
      }
    }, {}))
  );
}
getCustomPo(tenantId) {
    this._purchaseOrderService.getCustomPurchaseOrder(tenantId).subscribe({
      next: res => { this.customPo.next(res) }, // add a new value to the B.Subject
      error: err => console.log(err)
    })
}
```

Now, in your html, you can subscribe to the aggregated data with an `async` pipe. And, whenever you update the source BehaviorSubject, the aggregate will update.

```
// some.component.html
<div>{{customPoAggregate  | async}}</div>
```

Comment: Hi sorry I miss something important in my question and updated it. Is this still applicable?

Comment: Also i just want to use the data as MatTableDataSource

Comment: yes, you can still use the above pattern, you will just need to change the `.reduce(...` part to match your needs. You would just use the above in the html, e.g. `<mat-table #table class="table table-bordered table-sm" [dataSource]="customPoAggregate | async">`

Comment: Sorry the code is not running and has many error on typescript

Comment: The code in the answer is not complete angular code, just snippets. You will have to adapt it to your situation. If you link to a working example, we can help you troubleshoot the errors.